# Removing rows with multiple NAs with group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this toy data-frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,4),p_id=c(1001,1001,1002,1003,1004,1004),x=c(1,NA,1,2,NA,1),y=c(NA,5,4,NA,6,NA),z=c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,4))

id p_id  x  y   z
1  1001  1  NA  NA
1  1001 NA  5   NA
2  1002  1  4    2
3  1003  2  NA   3
4  1004 NA  6   NA
4  1004  1  NA   4
```

I would like to get the final output with unique 'p_id' rows and undesired NA values from x,y, and z (ideally, should work on any number of columns) removed. Example output:

```
p_id    x    y     z
1001    1    5     NaN
1002    1    4     2
1003    2  NaN     3
1004    1    6     4
```

I am doing this quick workaround (not sure best approach):

```
df %>% select(-id) %>% group_by(p_id) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean),na.rm=T) %>% ungroup()
```

However, this workaround is very slow when applied on large dataframe (2500 x 650) and it creates unwanted NAs for the normal cells. Also for context, the duplicated p_id rows with NA in this df are coming from the spread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by the 'id' columns, do a `summarise_all` by creating a condition with `if/else` to return `NaN` if all the elements in that column per group is `NA` or else take the non-NA element (in the example, there is only a single non-NA element, so we are subsetting it)

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, p_id) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(if(all(is.na(.))) NaN else .[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id [?]
#     id  p_id     x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  1001     1     5   NaN
#2     2  1002     1     4     2
#3     3  1003     2   NaN     3
#4     4  1004     1     6     4
```

---

If there are more than non-NA value per each group id combination, then we can use `mean` (as showed in the OP's post)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, p_id) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(if(all(is.na(.))) NaN else mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with `tidyr::fill()` followed by `summarize`

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%  
   fill(x,y,z, .direction = "up") %>% 
   summarise_all(first)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>      id  p_id     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  1001     1     5    NA
#> 2     2  1002     1     4     2
#> 3     3  1003     2    NA     3
#> 4     4  1004     1     6     4
```

Comment: TIL tidyr::fill. Performance-wise it is slower than akrun's solution above.